# jQuery maskedinput character not required

Tags: jquery, primefaces, maskedinput

I am using the inputMask-tag of primefaces which adds the maskedinput-plugin of jQuery to my application.

I have a input field with this mask:

```
***-999
```

The user should be able to leave some characters empty (e.g. for a search-form)

I´ve found this [post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795153/jquery-masked-input-plugin-to-not-clear-field-when-errored). So i changed my mask to:

```
?***-999
```

Here is a example-input:
_ _ _ 123 (user just enters the last 3 digits)

If the user unfocuses the input-field the input field contains this value:

123

If he focuses the input-field again it contains this value:

123-_23

Is there something i can do to make my example work?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still struggling I wrote similar plugin a while ago that masks fields and works fine with situation you described above. See example usage at:

http://tomaszegiert.seowebsolutions.com.au/maskit/index.html

Optional fields example you would be interested in is 23rd from the top if I counted correctly. I hope it will help someone.