# jquery masked input plugin to not clear field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, mask, jquery-mask

In my project I'm using these following plugins for validation

```
     jquery.validate.min.js, 
     jquery.ui.core.js,
     jquery.ui.widget.js, 
     jquery.ui.mask.js
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
     $('#txtShippingInfoPhone').mask({mask:"999-999-9999",clearEmpty: false});
```

By default input box is empty. like this

```
  Phone number:
```

when i keyup on that textbox its look like this

```
Phone number:___ ___ ____
```

And, If I enter wrong phone number then it is accepting. e.g:

```
 [407-555-____]
```

But here, error should through instead of accept the value.
Observation: Its consider __ __ ____ also value.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9795153/386579

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you validate the form, but if is the default proceedment, you are only checking if the field is not empty (required).

You need to check if the phone value match the mask before... and then continue with the validation.

Example

```
if($('#txtShippingInfoPhone').mask("valid")){
    /* It's valid, continue with the submit... */
    return true;
}else{
    /* It's NOT valid, trigger the error msg, and interrupt the submit... */
    return false;
}​
```

Comment: I got answer from some other question anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: @SenthilSivaramakrishnan If this is the answer to your question, why not mark this as the answer? If it is not, why not add an answer to point others to the answer you found?